# Multiple same directive share the scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Does controller share it's scope if I use the directive in one page multiple times? Although I think is not shared, I still want someone to help me understand this point.

If I define the variable 'isWidgetEnabled' in fooController, will it share in both two directives, if I want each directive 'foo' has its own variable, how can I do it?

**js:**

```
angular.module("module")
  .controller("fooController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    ...
  })
  .directive("foo", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      controller: "fooController",
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // Do some things with the scope of the controller here
      }
    }
  });
```

**html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Scripts here -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="module">
        <foo/>
        <foo/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be shared in all the directives, because the scope of your directive is *inherited* by default, which means that it shares the same scope as the controller.

Comment: if i add scope:{}, it will not share?

Comment: no, in that case each directive will have a separate isolate scope of themselves.

Comment: how can i have a variable controlled in each own directive?Could you help to give more explaination:)

Comment: Go through this: http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: Although the real problem i met is not solved, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Sure, this is a difficult concept to grasp. With time you will understand. There are a lot of resources out there, just go through them.

Comment: Could you help me to understand this:http://plnkr.co/edit/xpHoec?p=preview why i define the variable in controller, and it won't show in the template Here an isolated scope is mandatory, why controller variable is not working in isolate scope?

Comment: Frame this as a separate question so that other people can help too?

Comment: add new question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893982/why-variable-defined-in-the-directive-controller-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain a separate variable in the controller for each directive, you should pass these variables explicitly through the directive attributes and bind them to the isolated scope via Prefixes.

Here is an example. I have the `foo` directive in this code and the directive is used in two places in the dom. The directive modifies a scope variable depending on an attribute of the dom element it is caled.

The code is set to set the html of the `<span>` elements with the html of the directive elements.

```
<div ng-controller="fooController">       

   <div foo scopevar="dir1Data">Div1</div>   <!--Here you tell which controller variable to effect by the directive-->
   <div foo scopevar="dir2Data">Div2</div>

   <span>{{dir1Data}}</span><br>
   <span>{{dir2Data}}</span>         

</div>
```

And your angular code

```
.controller('fooController', function($scope) { 

    $scope.dir1Data = '';
    $scope.dir2Data = '';                       
})

.directive('foo', function(){
    return {

        scope: {

            //You set the prefix "=" here. This tells angular the variable name 
            //mentioned in the scopevar attribute should be two-way bound
            //to the controller scope 

            scopevar:'='  
        },

        link: function(scope, ele, attr) {
            scope.scopevar = ele.html();   //Here I modify the controller variable
        }
    }                
})
```