# Why variable defined in the directive controller not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

Why i defined 'sayHi' in the controller, and it does not display in the template?

**js:**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("directive1", function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope: {

        },
        link : function($scope){        

        },

        controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
          $scope.sayHi = 'hi';
          window.console.log($scope.sayHi);
        }]

    };  
});
})();
```

**html:**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid; padding: 10px; min-height: 100px;">
Directive1 :   
<directive1>
    {{sayHi}}
</directive1>
</div>
```

[detail plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpHoec?p=preview)

Comment: That controller is related to your first directive and not second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive doesn't have any template. You need to add

```
template: '{{ sayHi }}',
```

To your directive definition. The content inside the `<directive1></directive>` does not constitute the template of the directive.